# No such file or class on classpath (scala)

Tags: java, scala, maven, apache-spark

```
//package com.examples

/**
 * Created by kalit_000 on 27/09/2015.
 */
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark._
import java.sql.{ResultSet, DriverManager, Connection}
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage
import kafka.producer.Producer
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds,StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark._

object SqlServerKafkaProducer {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN)

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("MSSQL_KAFKA_PRODUCER")
    val sc=new SparkContext(conf)

    val driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    val url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=admin;password=oracle;database=AdventureWorks2014"
    val username = "admin"
    val password = "oracle"

    var connection: Connection = null
    Class.forName(driver)


    /*Create connection and statement to run against sql server and execute*/
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)
    val statement = connection.createStatement()
    val resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select top 10 CustomerID,StoreID,TerritoryID,AccountNumber from AdventureWorks2014.dbo.Customer")
    resultSet.setFetchSize(10);
    val columnnumber = resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount.toInt

    /*OP COLUMN NAMES*/
    var i = 0.toInt;
    for (i <- 1 to columnnumber.toInt)
    {
      val columnname=resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i)
      println("Column Names are:- %s".format(columnname))
    }

    /*OP DATA*/
    while (resultSet.next())
    {
      var list = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
      for (i <- 1 to columnnumber.toInt)
      {
        list.add(resultSet.getObject(i).toString())
        //println("Column Names are:- %s".format(columnname))
      }
      println(list)

      /*Buils kafka properties file*/
      val props:Properties = new Properties()
      props.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092")
      props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")

      /*send message using kafka producer.send to topic trade*/
      val config= new ProducerConfig(props)
      val producer= new Producer[String,String](config)
      //val x=list.collect().mkString("\n").replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(",","~")
      producer.send(new KeyedMessage[String, String]("trade", list.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(",","~")))


    }
    /*close SQL Server database connection*/
    connection.close()


  }


}
```

I built jar using Maven in intellijIDEA this is scala spark project the jar file is created using under folder `(C:\Users\kalit_000\IdeaProjects\SparkCookBook\target\SparkCookBook-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar)` when I tried to run the jar file using command

```
scala -classpath "C:\Users\kalit_000\IdeaProjects\SparkCookBook\target\SparkCookBook-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" SqlServerKafkaProducer
```

I am getting error which says 
Error:-

> No such file or class on classpath: SqlServerKafkaProducer.class

I can see my class inside the jar file I used Java decompiler software to open up Jar file.

can anyone help ?

I am able to compile in intellij Idea successfully.

Comment: try adding the full package path in front of the target class.

Comment: Could you try `scala -classpath "C:\Users\kalit_000\IdeaProjects\SparkCookBook\target\SparkCookBook-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" SqlServerKafkaProducer$`?

Comment: tried but no luck bro !

Comment: try using scala -classpath "C:\Users\kalit_000\IdeaProjects\SparkCookBook\target\SparkC‌​ookBook-1.0-SNAPSHOT‌​-jar-with-dependenci‌​es.jar" com.examples.SqlServerKafkaProducer